# OnclikListener and scroll on Google glass

Tags: android, google-glass, google-gdk

I have a pair of **Google glass** and I would like to install an **App for Tablet and smartphone** I developed myself.

The App use the API 19 as well as the the Glass.

In this app I have a button and the view is to long for the glass, so we are only able to see the above of the page.

For now i am **not able to scroll down** the page **nor to click** on the **button** in order to go to the next activity. (it works fine on tablet and smartphone)

Do you know if there is a way to make this work **without** having to use **CardViews** ?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually, it's hard to directly port a phone app to glassware. User interaction is totally different. I don't think you can literally click on the button using the touchpad so button's OnClickListener doesn't work.

Anyway, GDK has its own gesture listener API.
You can check it [here](https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/gdk/touch).

You can try detecting a scroll with ScrollListener:

```
gestureDetector.setScrollListener(new GestureDetector.ScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onScroll(float displacement, float delta, float velocity) {
            // do something on scrolling
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer. I try to use the "Detecting activity-level gestures" piece of code from the Google API but then my app doesn't launch anymore at all and i don't know why... Can we use the google glass API on a activity from a "normal" app ?

Comment: I don't remember, i will copy them on tomorrow because i don't have the glass tonight. but i am not sur if i can apply those methods on an app that does not use cardview, what do you think ?

Comment: I used it before. You don't need CardViews to get touch gestures.

Comment: Okay i succeed in using the TAP gesture, however i really don't know what to type in the method onScroll... I just want to be able to scroll down in order to scroll to the bottom of the page. Do you Have any idea on what it could look like ?

Comment: cardScrollView serve that purpose very well. whats the problem using that in your app ?

Comment: I thought that carScrollView could be apply on card object, i am going to try but since i don't use card to define activities i am not sure this will work